# how to decode the Teltonika FM1000 device. What is the decoder format for this device

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, gps, apache-mina

i am integrating the teltonika FM1000. but i don't know what is the exact decoder to parse the data. and also in their document they mentioned it as CODEC id 08. what is CODEC id 08

Comment: I suggest you ask them. If they don't know, no one does. If this is a general programming question, can you show us you code and what you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 3):

Codec ID 08 is just Teltonika internal ID for distinguishing one Teltonika device type from another. FM1100 uses 08 while for example GH4000 uses 07. This lets you create code that will parse Teltonika data differently according to device type (codec ID).

You can have a look at [Traccar](https://www.traccar.org) project as they support Teltonika FM message format.

Source code: [TeltonikaProtocolDecoder.java](https://github.com/tananaev/traccar/blob/fa01e90f6ee1381766d15494e57ccf7b3eb14ca5/src/org/traccar/protocol/TeltonikaProtocolDecoder.java)

There are some other classes with Teltonika prefix worth looking at.

Be aware that Traccar uses netty but the parser itself can be used for MINA.

Answer (score 1):

Teltonika engineers constantly adding new data blocks to the protocol - like BLE tags information or some new data from CAN/OBD bus - it means your parser need to be updated quite often. Also they sometimes release new firmware for same device like FM1000 mentioned, but a new version of it like FM1100 => FM1110, FM1120, FM1122, FM1125, ... and sometimes their IO ID mapping (meaning of parameter) is also changing.

So in order to always maintain good parsing results I recommend you either to install Traccar or any other open source platform mentioned above and update it on a regular basis or use any kind of cloud parsers for GPS/GSM devices and consume already parsed messages into easy-readable JSON, like [here](https://flespi.com/blog/how-to-access-messages-in-flespi-http-mqtt-and-more).

Disclaimer: I'm related to [flespi](http://flespi.com/) parsing backend and my opinion can be affected by the product I'm working on.